# Router assign ip to docker container

Tags: docker

In VirtualBox, I can create a vm with using Bridged Adapter. This vm has its own ip address. Thus, there will be 2 ip addresses pointing to the same machine. I want to know how I can do the same thing in docker container. I did try to launch the container with the flag `--net=bridge` but the ip address of that container is not assigned by router

Answer (score 2):

Launching the container with `--net=bridge` you are connecting the container with default Docker bridge (network 172.17.0.0/16), which is the default behavior for network configuration.
There is an open [issue in Docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4952) to implement this feature in an easy way. But now you will have to perform some actions manually to get what you want:

- You can create a new bridge to your local interface connected to the desired lan, which will emulate a switch. Check [this](http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/11/four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/) and [this](http://straightedgelinux.com/blog/howto/docker.html) to see examples of this approach.
- You can create a new ip link emulating the container interface for each container you create. You can see an example of this [here](http://blog.codeaholics.org/2013/giving-dockerlxc-containers-a-routable-ip-address/).